# How to call an API endpoint during runtime?

Tags: java, spring, api, runtime, endpoint

how can I call an API endpoint at runtime?
I'm new to this business
I have an endpoint in my spring project that saves products (a json file that is in the project) to MongoDB
I need products to be saved before the user uses my application

Comment: Read file on project start-up and save in db with `ProductService`? Why even call endpoint, if it's part of your project? Add some more details, it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Chaosfire , you understood correctly, this endpoint is necessary to add products manually, but due to the circumstances, we are forced to do such a trick (hard code) And. I don't understand how to call the endpoint at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a client to make the request at the appropriate time. There are lots of options, so i will list only a few:

1. Java provided functionality. Not really recommended, unless you want to learn the basics. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).
2. Apache [HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/). A simple get request example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://your.host/endpoint");
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(get);
YourClass response = mapper.readValue(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), YourClass.class);
```

3. Spring [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-webclient.html). There are more guides, just google them if you need. Simple get request example:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();
YourClass conversionResponse = webClient.get()
        .uri("https://your.host/endpoint")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(YourClass.class)
        .block(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Naturally there are more tools. Play around with them, and pick what's best for your specific need.